# Obtaining DocuSign OAuth IntegratorKey

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi

I'd like to make an app where I can allow users to authenticate into their own DocuSign account and manage their account through my app. I imagine the use of their OAuth API which will grant me an access token to make requests on behalf of their account.

However, it seems that DocuSign's REST API has me specify the user's IntegratorKey (in addition to email and password). From my understanding an IntegratorKey is only obtained through a developer account setup, which I don't want my users going through

Ref: http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/OAuth2/OAuth2%20Token%20Request.htm

Answer (score 0):

I believe SOBO will accomplish this for you.  With SOBO (Send On Behalf Of) functionality, you can send requests on behalf of other users that are in the same account.  The DocuSign Dev Center has a page dedicated to this feature and it lays out the steps needed and how the account needs to be configured.

Please read the following page for all the info:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo

Just to highlight some of the main points, you need to have the following settings enabled under account preferences to use SOBO:

```
- apiAccountWideAccess
- allowSendOnBehalfOf
```

And the general steps that you would take for SOBO are:

1. Obtain an access token for the :authenticating" user.
2. Obtain an access token for the "operating" user.
3. Send request on behalf of the operating user.

As mentioned, please refer to the following page for all the info you need for this feature:
http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo

Comment: hm, from the link that you posted https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo seems that both authenticating and operating users need to have IntegratorKey

Comment: and also weird, I have to ask users for their passwords, there is improper Oauth2 flow IIRC. The authenticating server should ask for credentials and then redirect back to me, isn't it?